# Kubuntu 18.04 LTS keyboard not working after installing synaptics

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, touchpad

I installed Kubuntu 18.04 LTS on an Asus Zenbook but the touchpad settings were missing options. I followed some advice and installed synaptics via

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Now my keyboard doesn't work. I can't remove the package without the keyboard because I can't type my sudo password and I can't install an on-screen keyboard for the same reason (sudo). I tried plugging an external keyboard in but that didn't work either.

Can anyone provide a solution that doesn't involve reinstalling the OS? I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I uninstalled synaptics without a keyboard:

I wrote out two commands and emailed them to myself from another computer.

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
<sudo password>
```

and

```
Y
```

The newlines are interpreted as 'Enter' by the shell. I could then copy and paste these into the terminal with the touchpad controls to remove the offending package.

Comment: Thanks mate.Special thanks for the new lines :), I had the same problem for Dell XPS 7590 and removing the synaptics solved the issue.